# Reverse-engineer an Oracle OLAP Cube in ODI 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I want to make **Multidimensional OLAP cube** in ODI, so I follow this guideline  [Oracle OLAP](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/odi/develop-connectivity-km/oracle_olap.htm#CHDFBAIE). But, ODI does not have **RKM Oracle OLAP** to import in Model.

Would you please guide me on how to create a MOLAP data cube in ODI?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found in the KM manuals, it seems that only ODI 10g it's supporting that version that you need (to reverse-engineer the OLAP cubes). I searched also in the manual for 12c/11g and I didn't find there any information about this RKM Oracle Olap. In the ODI 10g manual you can find a whole chapter about OLAP.

[Oracle 10g KM Developer Guide](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/oracledi-km-reference-130306.pdf)

[Oracle 11g KM Developer Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/odi/develop-km/E12645-04.pdf)

[Oracle 12c KM Developer Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/odi/ODIKD.pdf)

Maybe if you have a frind that can share to you the RKM from 10g, you could try to import into your version and see if it works.

**EDIT 1:**

### ROLAP/MOLAP Concepts in ODI

From what I read in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/odi/develop-connectivity-km/oracle_olap.htm) at chapter 23.1.1, we can understand that ODI accepts this concepts of ROLAP/MOLAP, beeing reversed from Oracle Olap cubes, but this doesn't mean that you can create them directly in ODI as a standalone object. They are depended to Oracle Olap Cubes. That means that you could create an ODI Model > ODI Datastore that have the Logical schema of Oracle Olap cubes, and then use it as an ROLAP/MOLAP.

**EDIT 2:**

### Create a cube and populate it

You could use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/develop/cubes_dimensions.htm#ODIDG9959) document in order to create a cube and create a mapping that populate that cube.

Step by step creating the cube from the above example link is [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/odi/odi_12c/odi_12.2.1.1/Cube_Dimensions/cube_dimensions.html).

Comment: Dear @F.Lazarescu, thank you for your feedback. But, I have to do that in ODI 12c. Would you please guide me if there is any way to make MOLAP cubes in ODI 12c?

Comment: Hi @M_Gh, please read my EDIT 1 from the above answer. I wrote there how you could do it.

Comment: Dear @F.Lazarescu, would you please guide me? In Oracle 12c or later to create Oracle Olap Cubes, we have to use **Analytic Workspace Manager(AWM)**. So, if AWM can handle it; what is the benefit of using ODI to create data cubes?

Comment: What is your scope, what do you need to obtain with this cube?

Comment: I have a transaction table of financial data. I must create a data cube of them. Then UI can run queries on the data cube without delay to report.

Comment: Dear @F.Lazarescu, thank you for your help. I had created a cube and dimensions according to the link before and the cube had been saved like a simple table in database. I think it is just ROLAP cube that I cannot run a query on it very fast, because it is not the pre-computed cube.